# Obscure Results and Areas of Mathematics

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, big-list, advice

My degree is in economics although I did relevant mathematics in college and used algebraic topology in my thesis. Over the Pandemic I've been reading a lot of mathematics that I didn't get a chance to in college. I now have very few major topics to cover on my list, and am starting to think of what to look at next in mathematics. I don't want to pick a subject like homological algebra because I have a little bit of abstraction vertigo right now. That's not to say I need easy proofs, the hardest I've gone through is a grad book on Riemann Surfaces to get my way to The Uniformization Theorem, to give an idea of where I'm at. So I'm looking for results or ideally mini-areas of mathematics to study which are pretty, accessible (at least in terms of statements of theorems, if not proofs) and off-the-beaten-path. Some great examples for me would be the theory of Sturmian words or the mathematics of origami.

Comment: Take care; If they are too much "off-the-beaten-path" they will lead you to "no-way-path". The first thing : what is your objective ? Do you want advices on "recreational mathematics" in the "Martin Gardner's style" for the pleasure or are you interested by advices on math-chapters-that-could-be-useful (non-void intersection between both directions!) ?

Comment: I don’t need something that connects to all of mathematics. I wouldn’t mind recreational mathematics suggestions. I find a lot of it is studying objects without nice properties, though. Anything with some degree of substance.

Comment: The first things that come to my mind are primarily connected to discrete maths and necessitate sooner or later a computer: 1) "cellular automata", 2) different sorts of fractals sets beginning for example by different generation modes for Sierpinski triangle and dragon curve, 3) Lindenmayer systems for generating plants 4) Different ways of paving the plane with polygons, either repetitive or not, etc.

Comment: I guess a lot depends on what you already know. How much probability and stochastic processes have you done? It might be something to try. Or try Mark Kac Statistical Independence in Probability, Analysis and Number Theory for a nice mix.